# openvpn between zentyal servers and normal clients possible?

Tags: vpn, openvpn, zentyal

I have a zentyal in a vps in the internet that I use to connect some companies with their external offices, so far with windows this is not a problem I connect the windows server to zentyal via openvpn client and configure as many openvpn clients as external offices that they have and they work perfectly but when I try to connect same way using zentyal in a company it fails, I mean I can check the option that states allow zentyal to zentyal tunnel. ok the server of the company can connect to the zentyal vps but I cannot download a bundle for normal clients to connect to the same network, is there a work arrout to connect both zentyals and normal hosts on a same netork via openvpn? If I try to use a normal client bundle in zentyal it doesnt let me connect.

Answer (score 0):

Zentyal to Zentyal connections don't work for normal clients.

Zentyal allows you to define more than one VPN server. You should use a *separate VPN server* for other clients.

Note that the two modes have different semantics, in regard to how routing works for each of the VPN models. In brief:

- Zentyal-to-Zentyal VPN tunnels use RIP and exchange the static routes accessible to each server.
- For normal "road-warrior" clients, networks that needs to be accessed by clients have to be published using the "Advertised networks" section.

In addition, it's better practice to use a separate VPN network for road warriors, another VPN for server-to-server communications.

If I guess correctly, you'd like to use Zentyal as a normal VPN client (using a normal client bundle). It's a requested feature but I believe it's not available. You could configure the OpenVPN client manually in the Zentyal box (unmanaged by Zentyal, unless you use hooks). Alternatively, you could use a Zentyal-to-Zentyal tunnel for all clients, but configure Windows clients manually based on the certificates present on the bundle and the  Windows OpenVPN configuration files you already have (this way, you'd be missing RIP (route exchange) funcionality between Windows and Zentyal but it shall work).

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, i think there is not way inside zentyal to manage S2S connection.
To achieved that i use one server as client (S2), download a Linux bundle from the other zentyal(S1) server, then configure the S2 to act as the others clients to connect to the S1.

here is a link for client side configuration [openpvn linux client](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/459675-configure-linux-clients-to-connect-to-openvpn-server)

Hope that help